# Checks if google maps installed

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a hybrid android application by using phonegap.
I want to navigate to maps by using the following code:

```
<a href="geo:32.5558485,34.65522447"></a>
```

How can I discover if the google map application is installed in the device. by HTML and/or javascript only.

Thanks in advance

Kobi

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to as when you click on that link Android will give you a list of apps that can handle the geo: url type.

If you really want to check if there is an app available to handle that URI scheme you'll need to [write a plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) to call some Java code:

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("geo:32.5558485,34.65522447"););
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```